# Replace table elements from text files with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have some data on a txt table:

```
Number        Column1        Column2
  1             abc            zxy
  7             tgh            lkj
  1             rfe            zpo
```

I want to replace the string in the position of lkj, (always in the 3rd column and line 3). Not replacing arbitrarly lkj. Thinking in another example:

```
    Number        Column1        Column2
  a             875            172
  a             457            357
  2             986            125
```

I would like to be extracted the 357 in this case. 3rd column 3rd line. 
I was trying something involving `awk`with a parameter `$3` for the column, but I don't know what else to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you care about the preservation of the manual alignment using spaces, i.e. is this meant to be a pretty `txt` file for human consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want preserve the well alignement use `awk` with `sub` function.

```
awk 'NR==3{sub($3, "string_to_replace")}1' infile.txt
```

else, you can use below instead

```
awk 'NR==3{$3="string_to_replace"}1' infile.txt
```

`NR==3` means do the replace if it's 3<sup>rd</sup> line, `1` is always true condition and telling `awk` print the line (or that's `awk`'s default action)